# Help with a geometry problem involving triangles

Tags: geometry, triangles

My geometry book doesn't explain things very well so..... yeah
I'm pretty sure that this has a simple answer, but my geometry book words it pretty weird.

> If triangle RST is congruent to triangle MNP and RT = MP, TS = PN, and angle T = angle P, give the corresponding parts; the equal parts.

Comment: Don't understand your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have two sides and the angle between them the same, so you just need to match up the other side and two angles.

- SR = NM
- angle S = angle N
- angle R = angle M